# Authorization with windows authentication in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, windows-authentication, iis-express

As I understand there is a way to retrieve group where user belong.
For example Admins, Users etc.

After doing that I want to transform this into claims. I cannot find how I can retrieve a user's groups.

Currently I am using my local user and not (Domain Active Directory).

Is there any solutions for that issue?

Is it a good approach or it is better to retrieve permissions for each user from the database and then operate with them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to know is that AD is working on **windows host only**.
read [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-3.1) before you start project

add startup configuration , create login page

```cs
services
.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
             .AddCookie(options =>
             {
                options.LoginPath = "/Login";
             });
.....

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

third your needs:

1. your AD domain :  yourdomain.com
2. your ldap url example: LDAP://DC.yourdomain.com
3. some knowledge about [ldap query string](https://theitbros.com/ldap-query-examples-active-directory/)

application.json config:

```json
"ldap": {
    "path": "LDAP://DC.yourdomain.com",
    "domain": "yourdomain.com",
    "personFilter": "(SAMAccountName={username})",
    "groupFilter": "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))",
    //"property": "cn,displayName,mail,givenName,sn,o,title,company,department,telephoneNumber,description,userPrincipalName",
    "property": "cn,displayName,mail,givenName,sn,o,title,company,department"
    //"property": "cn,member,memberof,sAMAccountName,primaryGroupToken"
}
```

and you can use this method to check username and password

```cs
public Dictionary<string, string> UserInfo { get; private set; }
public bool IsAuthenticated(string username, string password)
        {
            bool result = false;


            string domainAndUsername = Configuration["ldap:domain"] + @"\" + username;
            DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(Configuration["ldap:path"], domainAndUsername, password);
            try
            {
                Object obj = entry.NativeObject;
                DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
                search.Filter = Configuration["ldap:personFilter"].Replace("{username}", username);

                var propList = Configuration["ldap:property"].Split(',');
                search.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(propList);

                SearchResult searchResult = search.FindOne();
                if (null == searchResult)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                foreach (var propName in propList)
                {
                    UserInfo.Add(propName, GetProperty(searchResult.Properties, propName));
                }

                DirectoryEntry obUser = new DirectoryEntry(searchResult.Path);
                object obGroups = obUser.Invoke("Groups");
                var groupList = new List<string>();
                foreach (object ob in (IEnumerable)obGroups)
                {
                    DirectoryEntry obGpEntry = new DirectoryEntry(ob);
                    groupList.Add(obGpEntry.Name);
                }

                UserInfo.Add("group", string.Join(",", groupList));
                result = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new SysAuthException("Invalid Authentication", ex);
            }

            return result;
        }
```

when login success you can check all user info from userInfo property

sample code for login page (add claim and login state to net core pipeline):

```cs
    try
            {
                if (Authentication.IsAuthenticated(UserData.Username, UserData.Password))
                {
                    var claims = new List<Claim>() {
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, UserData.Username)
                    };

                    foreach (var item in Authentication.UserInfo)
                    {
                        claims.Add(new Claim(item.Key, item.Value));
                    }

                    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

                    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal, new AuthenticationProperties()
                    {
                        IsPersistent = UserData.RememberLogin
                    });

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserData.ReturnUrl))
                        return LocalRedirect(UserData.ReturnUrl);
                    return Redirect("/");
                }
            }
            catch (SysAuthException ex)
            {
                Error = ex.InnerException.Message;
            }
```

if you need to protect your page add `@attribute [Authorize]` in top of your page also you can check other claim for example roles or group with this attribute

sample code show current user info

```
    <div>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <caption>Current User Info</caption>
        @foreach (var claim in User.Claims)
        {
            <tr><td>@claim.Type</td><td>@claim.Value</td></tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```